# HealthKit KCALs not Increasing

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am saving calories burned to healthKit central repository but the issue is it does not increment the total amount of KCAL in the fitness app . Saving workout works well i can see the time duration and the calories burned but its not added into the total MOVE/KCALs. I can see the MOVE are incremented.

```
    class func savingWorkout(duration : Double , burnedEnergy : Double , completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> ()) {
    
    let healthKitStore = HKHealthStore()
    let totalEnergyBurned = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.kilocalorie(), doubleValue: burnedEnergy)
    
    let finish = Date() // Now
    let start = finish.addingTimeInterval(-duration) // 1 hour ago
            
    
    let metadata = [
        HKMetadataKeyGroupFitness : false,
        HKMetadataKeyIndoorWorkout : true,
        HKMetadataKeyCoachedWorkout : true
    ]
    
    
    let workout = HKWorkout(
        activityType: .functionalStrengthTraining,
        start: start,
        end: finish,
        workoutEvents: nil,
        totalEnergyBurned: totalEnergyBurned,
        totalDistance: nil,
        device: nil,
        metadata: metadata
    )
    

    guard let energyBurnedType =
        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier:
            HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned) else {
        fatalError("*** Unable to create an energy burned type ***")
    }

    let energyBurnedPerInterval = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.kilocalorie(),
                                             doubleValue: burnedEnergy)

    let energyBurnedPerIntervalSample =
        HKQuantitySample(type: energyBurnedType,
                         quantity: energyBurnedPerInterval,
                         start: start,
                         end: finish) as HKSample
    
    
    //3.  Save the same to HealthKit
     healthKitStore.save(energyBurnedPerIntervalSample) { (success, error) in
        
      if let error = error {
        print("Error Saving calories burned: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      } else {
        print("Calories saved")
      }
    }
    
        healthKitStore.save(workout) { result , error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }
           print("workout saved into HealthKit successfully ")
    }
    
}
```